# .net core razor pages multiple routing attributes

Tags: c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.1

I am using razor pages (not View/Controller), and my goal is to build the following two routes for the same page:

- /GetItem{id:int}
- /GetItem{title:string}

They should lead to two different "actions" `OnGetAsync(int id)` and `OnGetAsync(string title)`.

Initially, I wanted to use routing attributes inside the PageModel, but concluded that they aren't supported for RazorPages PageModel - is that correct? Now I'm trying to achieve that with the @page directives, but haven't found anything. I'd prefer not to use the routes "configuration setup", as I want to have my routes local to the page using them.

What would be the right way to approach this?

Thank you for clearing away my confusion!

Comment: Yes is a way to do it from Startup class.

Comment: Yes, but that's exactly what I don't want. Attributes is fine, @page is fine, but I don't want to do it in Startup.cs.

Comment: Then use constraint `@page "{id:int}"`

Comment: I want to support two different attribute possibilities. Something like `@page "{id:int OR title}`, which leads to two different methods `OnGetAsync(int id)` and `OnGetAsync(string title)`. Is this explanation understandable?

Comment: Yeah it is @Doidel.

Comment: ASP.NET Core is all about 'convention over configuration'. There's the easy way to do things, but the options are there to work around the built in conventions. The way to support routing outside of convention was built in `RazorPagesOptions.Conventions`, which can be configured in `Startup.cs`.  Otherwise, you would have to do something like have your `PageModel.OnGet()` manually check for string or int, and route accordingly.

Comment: Just for funsies I tried a few things.  Mostly ran into the following error `InvalidOperationException: Multiple handlers matched. The following handlers matched route data and had all constraints satisfied: Void OnGet(Int32), Void OnGet(System.String)`

Comment: Indeed, a `isNumeric` in a single `OnGet` would be my plan B. And does your answer mean that the razor pages `PageModel` indeed doesn't support routing attributes on the `OnGet`, e.g. `[HttpGet("{id}")]`?

Comment: Right, no routing attributes. Only the `@page` directive. It's actually a pretty powerful directive. You can only use it once per page, but it does look like you can map 2 different pages to the same route, but it still doesn't help your issue.

Comment: Alright, please feel free to sum your answers into an "Answer" which I can accept :) And thanks for trying in code by yourself!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have two handler methods with the same name* in a single Razor Page, regardless of any differences in parameter declarations. Handler methods do not form part of the routing selection process like action methods do in MVC.

The best way to achieve what you want is to use [named handlers](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods#named-handler-methods). Then you can choose whether you want to include the name of the handler method as part of the URL or as a query string value.

*You can't even differentiate handler method names by appending "Async" to one. As far as Razor Pages is concerned, `OnGet` and `OnGetAsync` are the same.